# Why is it printing an @ instead of \100?

Tags: python, variables, printing, while-loop

I have the following program:

```
x = 0

while x <= 10:
   print(x, '\10')
   x = x + 1
```

It then prints:

```
0 @
1 @
2 @
3 @
4 @
5 @
6 @
7 @
8 @
9 @
```

Instead of:

`1 \ 10`, `2 \ 10` And so on...

Why is the program doing this?

Comment: Because `'\100'` is `'@'`

Comment: Then how would i print `\100`?

Comment: `print("\\100")`. Read up on escape and special characters.

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld: why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're escaping the 10 with a `\` symbol and python is interpreting `\10` as a code for the `@` symbol instead. You can fix this by either placing an `r` character as a prefix for the string or by escaping the backslash with another one.

```
Fix:
    r'\10' #Raw string
Or:
    '\\10'
```